# Which UI frameworks are recommended to use with Backbone.js?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, uicomponents

Is there a recommended framework with UI widgets (like grids, trees. etc.), to use with Backbone?

I saw questions about integrating Kendo with Backbone.
Do you know other (and also free) frameworks that can work good with Backbone?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I think most js UI frameworks will play nice with backbone, because backbone itself gives you a great amount of freedom to do things the way you want to.

Because Backbone already makes use of jQuery (or Zepto, etc), the [jQuery UI library](http://jqueryui.com) is a natural fit. It will set you up with nearly everything you might want or need for basic web application UIs.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery UI works well with backbone.js you might also want to take a look at [Backbone UI](http://perka.github.com/backbone-ui/)